# WCF service giving Time Out error

Tags: c#, wcf, enterprise-architect

I have a `.Net service` which is used to connect to **Enterprise Architect API.** When directly running the `.exe` file, it is taking about 30 seconds to connect and get response. When registering the same service as **WCF service** and running it, it gave following error:

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
{67F4E0FA-46A7-4255-B084-69A9433D08C3} failed due to the following
error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT:
0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).
```

Solved the above error by following the steps given in [this link](http://blog.lieberlieber.com/2009/09/16/running-enterprise-architect-on-a-server/).

After that now the registered WCF service is taking about 4-5 minutes to connect and then it is giving an error, `"tjava.net.SocketTimeoutException:` Read timed out."

Comment: I don't know WCF but running EA as a service does not work. Have you searched Sparx' forum (it's a PITA, I know)?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that EA requires a "real" user to work properly.

The guys at LieberLieber apparently found a solution for it: [Running-enterprise-architect-on-a-server](http://community.sparxsystems.com/tutorials/556-28running-enterprise-architect-on-a-server)